# How to add text on circle and how to combine circle when zoom out different cicle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I have more than 1000 markers at 3 different location in my Map.
I read Lat and Long from a text file and render it in Google maps and create circle over them on the basis of country name. And count the number of markers in those circle.

**Now what i am not able to do is?**

(1) I have to print the text of count on those circle (How to do without using Cluster ?)

(2) When i zoom out circle overlaps . So whenever circle overlaps it should combine the 2 radius of these two circles and should make one big circle covering the markers of the two smaller (smaller 2 will now disappear resulting on total of marker on the bigger one only).

My full code to do this (http://prntscr.com/6kt30w) is :

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: './App_Start/TextFile/latLongList3.txt',
                dataType: 'text',
            }).success(function (data)
            {

                var s2 = data.replace(/^.*$/, " ").replace(/\r\n/g, " ");
                var array = s2.split(/[ ]+/g);
                var test = [].concat.apply([], array.map(function (array) { return array.split(/\s+/); }))

                var col1 = [];
                var col2 = [];
                var col3 = [];
                var j = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i <= test.length - 3; i = i + 3)
                {

                    col1[j] = test[i];
                    col2[j] = test[i + 1];
                    col3[j] = test[i + 2];
                    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(col3[j], col2[j]);
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                       {
                           position: myLatlng,
                           map: map,
                           title: 'Hello World! ' + col1[j]
                       });
                    markers.push(marker);
                    if (j > 0) {
                        LatLong[j] = myLatlng;
                    }

                    j++;
                }     
            })
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

I don't want to use `MarkerClusterer` because it is very small. Yes it's true that it will do the 2 tasks i want to accomplish but the problem i feel with it is when i have markers all over the country then MarkerClusterer just hovers over a very little part of the country whereas i want the circle to hover over all country wherever i have marker and it should have text on it. So if there is any alternative to make the size of cluster such that it  cover all the markers in the entire country(because my 1 country is full of markers) and has text on it than any way to do this is welcomed too.

Could some one please help  me in solving the 2 problems ?

Answer (score 1):

> I have to print the text of count on those circle (How to do without
>   using Cluster ?)

You can use the following to get count of marker from marker.length

```
var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
      data.photos[i].longitude);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
      markers.push(marker);
}
```

To add the count to circle, you can look at this [JSFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/MSY9a/1/).

I still have to look more your second problem

Comment: Thanks... but why this -1 i still not able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution of it.I simply used `MarkerClusterer` and got it done by increasing its size.

And it works perfectly for me.